# Understand AngularJS Minification

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I am about to deploy an angularjs app, I would like to minify my code, but it is still confusing for me

I would like for exemple to transform

```
**Controller**
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $location, $etc) {
  $scope.message = "Hello World";
});
**View**
<p>{{message}}</p>
```

To

```
**Controller**
myApp.controller('myCtrl',function($a,$b){$a.m="Hello World";});
**View**
<p>{{m}}</p>
```

I can use grunt to minify the code, is grunt can also reduce the variables names? Like changing **message** to **m** for exemple? And how the mapping will be done with the view?

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject your dependencies as strings, so that angular would know which variable does what. Just add a manual injection for each service:

```
myCtrl.$inject = ["$scope","$location","$etc"]; // <--- injection

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $location, $etc) {
  $scope.message = "Hello World";
});
```

There are other syntaxes you can use, but this one is pretty clear and modular.